# Website displays perfectly on mobile but Google says its content is wider than screen

Tags: php, html, mobile

Google sent an email today telling me that this URL https://tolelight.com.vn/chi-tiet-tin/34/vat-lieu-san-xuat-tam-lop-lay-sang-frp-vs-cac-loai-khac.html is not mobile-friendly and its content is wider than screen. I have used a private browser to check and it displays perfectly on mobile. How to fix it?

Comment: looks fine to you, looks fine to me, nothing to fix. It's an automated bot test, don't take its word on anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google is right, if you go with an iPad (2nd-3rd generation, mini; 768x1024px) then you have a horizontal scrollbar. You need to make sure, that your website is also an such devices displayed without an horizontal scrollbar. You already use bootstrap on your site, with this CSS framework you can easily create a complete responsive layout, there is no need to define own wrapper with a fixed width, just use the bootstrap classes for layout (as example the class `container`).

Comment: Could you check the code and tell how to fix it, please? I'm not a dev.

Comment: Try to replace `<div class="wraper">` with `<div class="container">`.

Comment: It passes the test now but the language flags are covered: https://imgur.com/a/yuw7XCx

Comment: Then you need to redefine the position of your language flags. Search in your CSS file for the declaration of the class, which is used for the language flags container and redefine the position values. I'm really sorry, but we are not here to fix all of your issues with your design!